# My jquery Ajax method is going in else part every time

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, phpexcel

My `jQuery` method -

```
jQuery("#upload_button").click(function(){
    var exceldata = jQuery("#upload_button").serialize();
    var url = "module/controller/contrlrmethod/exceldata/" + exceldata;
    if( exceldata != "" )
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        alert("I am in else");
    }
});
```

Controller method -

```
public function contrlrmethodAction()
{
    //Get All Parameter data
    $params = $this->_getAllParams();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($params);die;
}
```

I am uploading Excel Sheet via this button `upload_button`. But every time it is  going in else part, whether I upload an excel or not. Let me know what I am doing wrong. I am using PHPExcel library to handle data further but its always going in else part.

Comment: `jQuery("#upload_button").serialize()` must be returning `empty string`. Why would you want to serialize a button?

Comment: use alert to output what `exceldata` contains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not sure , but looks like you are serializing the button..

```
var exceldata = jQuery("#upload_button").serialize();
                        --^^^^^^----here
```

it should be your forms id instead.

```
var exceldata = jQuery("#formID").serialize();
```

and some other errors...since you are using ajax post ..you can send data by `data` option no need to pass serialize data in url.

```
  var url = "module/controller/contrlrmethod/exceldata/";
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: exceldata,  //<--here
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
```

**NOTE:** if in case you are trying to upload files using ajax post.. then it is not possible, either you have to use iframe ... or use some other ajax file uploading plugins

Comment: If he's actually trying to upload a file though, he'll need to change a few more things to get it working.

Comment: @bipen bingo..this is the case :) +1

Comment: thanks.. :).. happy coding.. and update my answer please checkit out... let me know if any problem exists

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload files using AJAX. You have to make old-style POST on your form.

At the other hand, if you want to send form using ajax, you need to serialize whole your form, not only a submit button.

```
var serializedForm = $("form").serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'module/controller/contrlrmethod',
        type: 'POST',
        data: serializedForm,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

But as I said, this code don't upload a file. It just repairs your form post.